# Whenever i enter a new url and press click a new image is displaying but the previous image is still there i need to clear the previous image using js

Tags: javascript, html

Bhtm

```
<body>

  enter your url<input type="url" id="image">

  <button type="button" onclick="display()">click</button>

  <script>
    function display()

    {

      var myimage = document.createElement("img");

      myimage.src = document.getElementById("image").value + "#" + new Date().getTime();

      myimage.style.width = "100px";

      myimage.style.height = "120px";

      document.body.appendChild(myimage);

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seen as the only thing that changes each time is the URL, you could just use a global var to store a reference to the image element, and then just change it's url.

eg.

```
<script>
 var myimage;
 function display()
 {
   //only create image 1 time..
   if (!myimage) {
      myimage = document.createElement("img");
      myimage.style.width = "100px";
      myimage.style.height = "120px";
      document.body.appendChild(myimage);
   }
   myimage.src = document.getElementById("image").value + "#" + new Date().getTime();
}
</script>
```